# Placing an image logo in a pure CSS content tab

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a website that reveals content via labelled radio buttons (does not use scripts).

However, I'd like to achieve [**this specific layout**](http://alejcho.weebly.com) using radio buttons (this one uses `<a href='#'>` instead - which I don't want to use because pressing the tabs leaves a hash at the end of the URL and pressing 'back' on the browser loads up a previously clicked tab instead of the previous page).

So how do I go about making tab 'Logo' appear centrally above 'Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3'? (using that exact logo image? dont worry about its :hover effect for now) And clicking upon it will trigger the appearance of the first content box (tab 0)? And also how to do it without messing up the transitions/styles or shifting the position of any of the 4 overlaying content boxes (`<divs>`)?

Every attempt I've made (like removing the unordered list and separating the divs from the labels) destroyed the layout.

Thanks in advance!

```css
html {
    background-color: #444;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    color: #fff;
    font: 16px'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 26px;
}
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}
.tabs {
    padding: 0px;
}
.tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tabs label {
    color: #8C8C8C;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65), 4px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65), -4px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65), 0px -4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    transition: all 0.55s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
.tabs label:hover {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), 4px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), -4px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), 0px -4px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}
.tab-content {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55), transparent);
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
[id^=tab]:checked + label {
    text-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), 4px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), -4px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65), 0px -4px 8px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    color: white;
    top: 0;
}
[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] {
    opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
.fade-in {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -moz-animation-duration:1s;
    animation-duration:1s;
}
.fade-in.zero {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .2s;
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
.fade-in.one {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .6s;
    animation-delay: .6s;
}
.fade-in.two {
    -webkit-animation-delay: .9s;
    -moz-animation-delay: .9s;
    animation-delay: .9s;
}

.fade-in.three {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1.2s;
    animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab0" checked>
        <label for="tab0" class="fade-in zero">Logo</label>
        <div id="tab-content0" class="tab-content">
            <p>Welcome to this page!</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1">
        <label for="tab1" class="fade-in one">Tab 1</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tab 1 contains images and links!</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
        <label for="tab2" class="fade-in two">Tab 2</label>
        <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tab 2 contains more images and links!</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
        <label for="tab3" class="fade-in three">Tab 3</label>
        <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
            <p>Tab 3 has even more images and links!</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/alejcho/uan89equ/)

Answer (score 2):

Either I don't quite understand your issue or it is as simple as adding the logo above the `<ul>` - since the logo is always present in your design, it doesn't need to sit inside one of the fade-in-animated tabs.

See this fiddle for details: http://jsfiddle.net/polarbirke/uan89equ/1/